# Windows Firewall Add Route with Remote IP's?

Tags: delphi, windows-firewall

I’m building a software that is capable of allow open port’s under certain conditions for some IP’s (v4). I have this code to add the route. Work fine:

```
procedure TfrmMain.AddAntiHookAllowRuleTest();
var
 fwPolicy2       : INetFwPolicy2;
 newRule         : INetFWRule;
begin
    // Create the FwPolicy2 object
    fwPolicy2   := INetFwPolicy2(CreateOleObject( 'HNetCfg.FwPolicy2' ));

    // Create a Rule object
    newRule := INetFWRule(CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FWRule'));

    // Configure Rule object
    newRule.Name := 'AHOOK_SELF_ALLOW_RUTE';
    newRule.Description := 'Permitir todas las conexiones al Anti Hook a distintos puertos basado en el IP de los usuarios';
    newRule.Applicationname := Application.ExeName;
    newRule.Action := NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
    newRule.Direction := NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
    newRule.Protocol := NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
    newRule.LocalPorts :=  '8080,8081';
    newRule.Enabled := true;
    newRule.InterfaceTypes := 'LAN';

    //newRule.Grouping := 'CCN Antihook';

    //Add a new rule object
    FwPolicy2.Rules.Add( newRule );
end;
```

But I need to be able of add or remove some IP’s in the Remote Address Section of the Scope. In Windows Firewall, when editing a route object this can be done in Scope Tab. How I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

FYI: I import the NetFwTypeLib_TLB. Is more easy with this lib.

Comment: `newRule.RemoteAddresses` is probably what you're looking for. Possible content possibly as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netfw/nf-netfw-inetfwrule-get_remoteaddresses) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netfw/nf-netfw-inetfwrule-put_remoteaddresses).

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz yeah thanks. My despite !